# Is it possible to use a SignalR ASP.NET Server and SignalR WinForms App Client?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, signalr.client

I want to use SignalR to create communication between 3 simple Windows Forms apps and a ASP.NET Web API server.
I set up the server according to the Microsoft documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio. I even followed the PluralSight course 'Getting Started With ASP.NET Core SignalR', but that seems to be a little bit outdated.

```cs
[HubName("MyNetworkHub")]
    public class NetworkHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly ISomeService_someService;
        public NetworkHub(ISomeService someService)
        {
            _someService = someService;
        }

        public Task SendMessage(string message)
        {
            return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
        }
    }
```

In `Startup.cs` I added configuartion:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    ...
    services.AddSignalR();
    ...
  }
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
  {
    ...
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
         endpoints.MapControllers();
         endpoints.MapHub<NetworkHub>("/networkhub");
      });
  }
```

For my clients I want to use Windows Forms Applications, because I'm building a simple prototype on a complex technology. I created 1 Console App to try out connection, like so:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
...
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            HubConnection connection = null;
            try
            {
                connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .WithUrl("http://127.0.0.1:52366/MyNetworkHub")
                    .Build();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            
            // The part below might be wrong, but I can't fix that if the connection doesn't work.
   
            connection.On<string>("ReceiveMessage", (message) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            });

            await connection.StartAsync();
        }
    }
```

I've seen a few examples of people trying the same thing, but all of them ran into issues with connection. The issue I'm running into is that I cannot start a connection, because I'm getting:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
```

I tried swapping the `.WithUrl("http://127.0.0.1:52366/MyNetworkHub")` to `.WithUrl("http://127.0.0.1:52366/networkhub")` but that results in the same error.

Comment: Where do you get that exception? Post the *full* exception text, not just the message. Which NuGet package did you use? The error complains about a missing assembly, not the URL. Perhaps you used the wrong package? Or there's a conflict with another package? What does your csproj look like?

Comment: I think I found the issue, used wrong versions in server and client... It looks like the client can connect now, but I have to downgrade the client's version from 5.0.0 to 1.0.0, seems a bit weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the issue with adding the `System.Text.Encodings.Web` package into the .csproj of the Client.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```